# Preciso mudar a fonte de um text-Area: Ex: de Negrito para itálico, mas não consegui ainda. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

```
var textarea = document.querySelector(".editor");
var negrito = document.querySelector("button");
var paragrafo = document.createElement('p');


negrito.onclick = function(){ 
    var select =  document.getSelection(".editor");
    var italico = document.createElement('i');
    var texto = document.createTextNode(select.toString());
    italico.appendChild(texto);
    console.log(select.italico());

}

textarea.onkeypress= function(){



}
```

Answer (score 0):

No exemplo abaixo eu pego o valor selecionado pelo usuário, uso um regex para obter somente o texto do textarea, e crio um novo texto acrescentando a tag selecionada pelo usuário e por último adiciono esse novo texto ao textarea.

```js
function opcaoSelecionada(val){
  if(val) {
    let text = document.getElementById('area').value.replace(/(<(&nbsp;|[^>]+)>)/ig, "");
    text = `<${val}>${text}</${val}>`;
    document.getElementById('area').value = text;
  }

}
```

```html
<textarea id="area"></textarea>

<select onchange="opcaoSelecionada(this.value)">
      <option value="">Selecione uma opção</option>
      <option value="b">Negrito</option>
      <option value="i">Italico</option>
</select>
```